# Show that under certain conditions the factors of direct product are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G = A \times B$. Also there exists some subgroup $D \le G$ such that
>   $$
>   G = AD = BD
>  $$
>   and $A \cap D = B \cap D = 1$. Then $A \cong B$.

In different words, it means that if $G$ is the direct product of $A$ and $B$ and the semi-direct product of $A,D$ and of $B, D$ then $A \cong B$.

The following mapping seems promising for an isomorphism: If $a \in A$, then $a = bd$ uniquely, so we can map $a$ on $b$, i.e. set $\varphi(a) := b$. This map is a bijection, but by establishing the homomorphic relation I got stuck, let $a = bd, \hat a = \hat b \hat d$, then $d = b^{-1} a, \hat d = \hat b^{-1} \hat a$, so that
$$
 b \hat b \hat d d = b \hat b \hat b^{-1} \hat a b^{-1} a = b \hat a b^{-1} a = b b^{-1} \hat a a = \hat a a
$$
(where the elements of $A$ and $B$ commute with each other because $G$ is a direct product of both), so that $\varphi(\hat a a) = b \hat b = \varphi(a) \varphi(\hat a)$, i.e. I got an anti-isomorphism, but what I want is an isomorphism.

So any ideas? Am I on the right track? Could this be fixed...

Comment: Why not use $\phi(a) = b^{-1}$?

Comment: Haha, yes too simple. Sometimes I am just blind, thank you!

Comment: @Stefan: You could look also at the projection from $G$ to the first coordinate, and restrict it to $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your conditions it follows that $B \cong (A \times B)/A = G/A = AD/A \cong D/(A \cap D)= D$ (as usual with internal direct products, $A$ is identified with $A \times \{1\}$.). Similarly $A \cong D$. Hence $A \cong B$.

Comment: Seems to be the most elegant solution, let me note that in a semi-direct product $G = NH$ we always have $G / N \cong H$, as you have directly shown by the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the addition, and glad you liked it.